# Folder transfer Mac OSX to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, macosx, transfer

I'm trying to transfer files from my old Mac OSX to my new laptop running Ubuntu 12.04.

I've drag and dropped the folders onto an external HDD formatted as HFS+.

When I drag and drop these folders onto my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop (will sort them later) some of the folders transfer fine whilst others do not as either

a.The folder "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" cannot be handled because you do not have permissions to read it or 
b. There was an error copying the file into /home/xxxx/Desktop/xxxxx and under more info says Error opening file: Permission denied.

1) If it's a matter of alt-F2 and running `gksu nautilus` why do some folders require this whilst others do not?
2) what's the underlying basis for this need?
3) is there an easier recommended way for transferring my files over from MacOSX to Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance
T

Comment: I have no clue about MacOS but it might help you to keep in mind that file permissions are stored using numeric user IDs. These need not be the same for the same username on different computers. It could be that some of the folders on your HDD have read permission for other users (these copy fine) while others don't. I'd copy them as root and then change file ownership.

Comment: Thanks soulsource. As to the practicalities of that copying as root involves gksu nautilus command and working within that window only yes?  How do I then change file permissions afterwards and what would be the issue if I failed to do this after the copying(for my own knowledge)? A GUI method is preferable as I feel less likely to mess up my system.. thanks

Comment: Yes, running Nautilus with gksudo will give you a file manager with root privileges. After copying the files, you should be able to set the owner user and group in the file properties dialogue, again in the nautilus window running with root privileges. After copying the worst thing that could happen would be files owned by a user different from your normal one. As root you can delete them (actually as root you can delete any file, so be careful).

Answer (score 1):

So thanks for all the above help.

For future readers looking to migrate their files from a Mac OSX to Ubuntu I can confirm that using an ethernet/crossover cable and setting up a direct link between the two is the easiest (in my experience) in terms of speed and ease. I've done in one evening what would have taken a week and an enormous amount of headache in terms of file size, external HDD format etc using an external HDD. No problem with permissions. Blisteringly fast transfer rates. Uses the samba file sharing protocol.

Instructions on how to connect a Macbook Pro and a device running Ubuntu can be found here 
http://wwharticles.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/how-to-connect-mac-to-ubuntu-pc-using.html

I used a crossover cable but apparently this isn't necessary for a Mac anyway as it can reverse lead polarities so a standard ethernet cable should work fine.

I can't recommend this enough for those looking to migrate from Mac OSX to Ubuntu (or just transfer large files).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a FAT based physical media, as permissions wouldn't be an issue.
Also, as your new computer is linux, I doubt you will be wanting HFS.

Or you could skip the physical media, and transfer the files over a network with `scp`, `rsync`, `ftp`, `sftp` etc...

If your new computer has a firewire port, you could always boot the mac into Target Disk mode, and content the mac to the new computer as an external directly.

Comment: Thanks demure. I avoided FAT as has a file size limit of 2GB(?) but then I've just realised I've already copied all my movies across without a permissions issue so this may be an option for the rest of my files which are likely smaller than 2GB..    Transferring over a network would be via an ethernet cable I take it? I'll look up tutorials for those. Pretty sure no firewire port on my new laptop. Are you able to comment on the above questions just for my ongoing knowledge? Thanks again

Comment: @user160992 FAT32's file size limit is 4gb; but exFAT's is 16 Exbibytes (but you would have to install the drivers to use). Ethernet would be faster then wireless, yes.